# DynamoDB Query confusion

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table creation code for DynamoDB (C#):

```
client.CreateTable(new CreateTableRequest
{
    TableName = tableName,
    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput { ReadCapacityUnits = 20, WriteCapacityUnits = 10 },
    KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
        {
            new KeySchemaElement
            {
                AttributeName = "RID",
                KeyType = KeyType.HASH
            }
        }
    ,
    AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>
        {
            new AttributeDefinition {
                AttributeName = "RID",
                AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.N
            }
        }
});
```

the data that gets populated into this table comes from this JSON:

```
[
{"RID": 208649, "CLI_RID": 935476,  "PRT_DT": "VAL_AA", "DISTR": "INTERNAL"},
{"RID": 217427, "CLI_RID": 1009561, "PRT_DT": "VAL_BB", "DISTR": "INTERNAL", "STATE": "VAL_BD"},
{"RID": 223331, "CLI_RID": 1325477, "PRT_DT": "VAL_CB", "DISTR": "", "STATE": "VAL_CD", "FNAME": "VAL_CE", "START": "VAL_CF"},
{"RID": 227717, "CLI_RID": 1023478, "PRT_DT": "VAL_DB", "DISTR": "", "STATE": "VAL_DD"}
{"RID": 217462, "CLI_RID": 1009561, "PRT_DT": "VAL_BB", "DISTR": "", "STATE": "VAL_BD"},
{"RID": 218679, "CLI_RID": 1009561, "PRT_DT": "VAL_AA", "DISTR": "INTERNAL"},
{"RID": 222376, "CLI_RID": 1263978, "PRT_DT": "VAL_DB", "DISTR": "", "STATE": "VAL_DD"}
]
```

How would I Query or Filter for all records containing 1009561 in column "CLI_RID" and column "DISTR" <> "INTERNAL"?

There will be about 15 mil records in this DynamoDB table.

Is my table defined correctly for this query/filter?

**Updated table creation:**

```
// CLI_RIDIndex
var cli_ridIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex
{
    IndexName = "cli_ridIndex",
    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
    {
        ReadCapacityUnits = 20,
        WriteCapacityUnits = 10
    },
    KeySchema = {
        new KeySchemaElement
        {
            AttributeName = "CLI_RID", KeyType = "HASH"
        }
    },
    Projection = new Projection { ProjectionType = "ALL" }
};


client.CreateTable(new CreateTableRequest
{
    TableName = tableName,
    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput { ReadCapacityUnits = 20, WriteCapacityUnits = 10 },
    KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
        {
            new KeySchemaElement
            {
                AttributeName = "RID",
                KeyType = KeyType.HASH // Partiton Key (Unique)
            },
            new KeySchemaElement
            {
                AttributeName = "CLI_RID",
                KeyType = KeyType.RANGE // Sort Key
            }
        }
    ,
    AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>
        {
            new AttributeDefinition {
                AttributeName = "RID",
                AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.N
            },
            new AttributeDefinition {
                AttributeName = "CLI_RID",
                AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.N
            }
        },
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes = { cli_ridIndex }
});
```

But when attempting to query it,

```
var request = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = "TNAArchive",
    KeyConditionExpression = "CLI_RID = :v_cli_rid",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
        {":v_cli_rid", new AttributeValue { S =  "905466" }}}
};

var response = client.Query(request);
```

I get this error:

```
Query condition missed key schema element: RID
```

I guess I'm not really understanding how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your table structure, you won't be able to perform **Query** on the table but you have to **Scan** it which we need to avoid.

To perform Query you need to modify certain things

1) Add a Global Secondary Index(GSI) with the field **CLI_RID** as Hash

2) Now You Query GSI by passing CLI_RID and add query filter with condition <> your value

Here is the reference [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html).

**Edit:** Your Main table structure will be same no need to change, but you need to add one more GSI with Hash key as CLI_RID and project required table attribute.

Now you need to query your GSI instead of the table with a hash key as CLI_RID, you don't need to pass RID here.
[here is the link on how to add GSI on table.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSILowLevelDotNet.html#GSILowLevelDotNet.CreateTableWithIndex)

If CLI_RID is not present in a master table then that record will not be reflected in the GSI so no need to worry.

**Edit 2:**  Just add (IndexName = NameOFYourIndex) attribute while querying and everything should work.

```
var request = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = "TNAArchive",
    IndexName = "NameOfYourIndex",
    KeyConditionExpression = "CLI_RID = :v_cli_rid",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
        {":v_cli_rid", new AttributeValue { S =  "905466" }}}
};
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Will I also have to include a RID value in the query? Can you show me the structure to use? Some records may not have a CLI_RID value.

Comment: In the example on the link you provided, I do not see where the creation of the secondary index defined what column the index was on.